# How to multiply 2 polynomial use Linked List with out power variable?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

My teacher let me  use linked list to make a polynomial like as this code

```
class Node {
    public:
        int data; // only data, has no power
        Node* next;
};
class PolyList {
    private:
        Node* pHead;
     public:
        PolyList();
        ~PolyList();
         ............
}
```

List is read by file input.txt.
Example : 2 4 0 3 ---> Polynomial =  ( 2x^3 + 4x^2 + 3 )

**How can i implement method multiply 2 polynomial between list1 and list2.**
I search google and on this site but only found polynomial is created with data include coefficient variable and power variable. My polynomial have only coefficient and i can not change this structure.
I need help from everybody. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution) of the coefficients.  If you have access to Matlab (or Octave), you can try it out:

```
% Note this is Matlab, just for demonstration
p1 = [1 1];  % x + 1
p2 = [1 0];  % x
p3 = conv(p1, p2)   %x*(x + 1) => x^2 + x

% gives p3 = [1 1 0], i.e., x^2 + x
```

Edit:  I didn't give any details about implementing this - You can probably find examples of convolution using linked lists by googling it.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it can be the following:

```
list<int> multiply(list<int> l1, list<int> l2) {
  int m[l1.size() + l2.size() - 1]; // Only positive powers of l1 "augments" the powers of l2!

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < l2.size(); i++) {
      m[i + j] += l1.get() * l2.get();
      l2.next();
    }
    l2.reset();
    l1.next();
  }
  list<int> to_ret;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
    to_ret.push_back(m[i]);
  return to_ret;
}
```

You put the coefficient of the `i`-th power of the resulting polynomial in `m[i]`.
To fill `m`, it's sufficient to iterate over every couple (i, j) of [0, l1.size) x [0, l2.size) and put in `m[i + j]` the coefficient you get multiplying the coefficient of the `i`-th power of the first polynomial with that of the `j`-th power of the second one.

Comment: probably because it is not very constructive to post answers to homework verbatim

Comment: but you should recognize that meaningful answers to questions of this kind are not far away from pseudo-code inclusion, like I did.

Comment: @akappa seem is only use with 2 list have the same length ?

Comment: @CongBinh it mimicks the way you'd multiply two arbitrary polynomial, factorizing common factors at each step, so it works even if l1.size() != l2.size().

Answer (score 1):

You could use two nested for-loops to multiply the two lists together, while saving them in another list: (pseudocode)

```
define list3 as a new PolyList of length x + y

for each element A at index x in list1
   for each element B at index y in list2
       save list3 element at index x + y as (A * B + (element at index x + y))
```

So for example with x^3 - 2x + 1 * x^2 + 4 = [1, 0, -2, 1] * [0, 0, 1, 4] = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, -8, 4].

***Note:** Your resulting list can be up to **twice** the size of the original length of the two arrays, because for example x^3 * x^3 = x^6, which would be recorded in the 6th index, starting from the right.*

***Also note:** The two arrays must be the same length for the algorithm to work properly! If this isn't assumed by the function you're creating, you will have to handle this situation.*

A good way to figure out how to program a problem like this is to imagine *exactly* the steps you would do to solve the problem, write those down, and then translate that into the language you're using.

Comment: Thanks but it is difficult to manager with 2 list have no same length. Can you give me the tip for this case ?

Comment: if one polynomial has a smaller degree than another, pad the polynomial of the smaller degree with zeros until they are the same length. For example: x^3 + 1 * x^2 + x = [1, 0, 0, 1] * [2, 1, 0] = [1, 0, 0, 1] * [0, 2, 1, 0] (note you must pad the left end of the list not the right end.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to multiply two polynomials of order M and N then the resulting polynomial will be of order M + N. So you need to create an output linked list whose length is the sum of the lengths of the two input lists. You then just iterate through the two input lists multiplying and summing the terms into the output list.

Hint: you might want to try doing this by hand first, i.e. with pencil and paper, so that you understand the process before you try to code it.